# Tool for creating jar files from command line

Tags: java, jar, command, cmd, prompt

I'm not very skilled in writing batch files and/ or java. I have a folder with several `.class-Files` and folders in it and I want to put them all into a executable `.jar-File`. I know that there is a tool called "jar - The Java Archive Tool", but that just won't work for me. My folder structure looks like this:

> - - - Folder "test"
> - - File (a.class)
> - - Folder "subdirectory"
> - File (b.class)

I want a executable `.jar-File` called *`file.jar`*. In this .jar should now be the file `a.class` and the folder *`subdirectory`* with the file *`b.class`* in it.

I don't get the `.jar-Tool` to run and the 7zip command line doesn't support `.jars` (I can't even add files to it). I want this to run from a `.bat-File`, so I just have to open the batch-file, it creates the `.jar` and puts the files in it and then closes itself again.

I hope you can help me and get what I mean.

Comment: what happens when you use jar?  Why can't you get it to run?  Do you have a manifest file?

Comment: Have you installed a JDK to get the jar command?

Comment: I used it like this:
`jar cf C:\fie.jar C:\files`

Yep, JDK is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Create a text file (and call it something useful like manifest.txt).  In it, put the line: 
`Main-Class: a` 
(which should be called A by convention) and include a hard return at the end.

Then create the jar with:
`jar cvfm file.jar manifest.txt *.class`
or 
`jar cvfm c:\somedir\file.jar c:\somedir\mainfest.txt *`

You could just put that line in a batch file called createJar.bat and run it if you only want to create files called 'file.jar'

hth

Comment: Thanks, can I set the path to where the file.jar should be created and where the class-Files are? Can I use *.* instead of *.class to put all files and folders into the .jar?

Comment: a path in front of the input and output locations should work, and *.* will put everything in the jar.

Comment: Hm... Does not work... It says `at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method) [...] at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1177)`

Comment: lol at '.'  It should be star dot star, but instead it looks like you have to call jar from the top level dir your files are in.  Your batch file will need to do the directory change to that dir and then run jar:  `jar cvfm c:\somefile\file.jar manifest.txt star

Answer (score 0):

If you have issues in executing jar command, then probably you would need to check if your path has been set correctly.  You can verify if the path contains jdk location ( echo %path%)  from command prompt. If not you need to update. Also you can verify using Javac -verbose command to see jdk is installed.

Once you have jdk path set,  you can try below command to create jar

Jar -cf  myapp.jar * -->  includes all files including files from sub folders.

If you want to run from batch,  you would need to mention path before jar command. Ideal place for path is to configure as environment property.

Comment: Yay, that works, but I can't set the path to the .jar-File.
Why does `jar -cf C:\file\file.jar *` not work? It says that it can't find the directory and/ or file, but the path is correct and the file exists.

Comment: Oh, I'm not allowed to use spaces in the directory names O_o? If I do this it won't find the folder, If I don't it works. One more question, can I set the path to the directory with the files to add? When I type `jar -cf C:\file\file.jar C:\data\` it creates a .jar-File with the folders `C: -> data -> +files` in it...

Comment: not clear what exactly you want to achieve! What you meant by 'setting path to the directory with files to add' ?